# Compiling and running my tvOS project with the new Xcode13+, the tab bar scrolls with the scrollView and I can't access the split view controller

Tags: ios, scrollview, uisplitviewcontroller, tvos, xcode13

When I compile and run my tvOS project with the new Xcode13+, the tab bar scrolls with the scrollView, and I can't access the split view controller moving the focus.

The issue doesn't happen with Xcode < 13. However, after updating to Monterey, I don't have a choice.

*Pre-condition:*

1. Create an app on tvOS with a tab bar controller;
2. In one of the tab, put a split view controller;
3. In the collapsed master view controller, put a table view.

*Issue 1:*

Observe that moving the focus towards the left to open the collapsed master view controller, doesn't work anymore. The master view controller won't be pulled out.  The only way to pull it out is to tap the back button (ex menu button).

*Issue 2:*

Scrolling down on the tableView in the master view controller would also scroll away the tab bar at the top (this was possible only setting the `tabBarObservedScrollView` before, but now is deprecated and it happens automatically. Even using `[self setContentScrollView:nil forEdge:NSDirectionalRectEdgeAll]` doesn't help.

---

Did anyone get the same problem? Do you know why this happens and if it can be solved?
In the meantime, I reported the problem to Apple.

PS. another odd thing is that the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/3816781-setcontentscrollview?changes=latest_beta) for `setContentScrollView:forEdge:` is empty (as of today).

### Update:

Observe how even setting the property to nil, it is still populated:
[image]

After deeper investigation, I found that the problem happens only when compiling with Xcode13+ and running on tvOS15+.

For some reason, the property above is automatically populated for ALL `UITableViewController`.

Replacing the `UITableViewController` with a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` inside solves the Apple issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with Apple SDK:

Observe how even setting the property `tabBarObservedScrollView` to nil, it is still populated:
[image]

This happens for ALL `UITableViewController`.

Replacing the `UITableViewController` with a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` inside wor the Apple issue.

--

Regarding the swipe left, it's another Apple bug or decision to not allow the focus to move on the master view controller when on a split view controller.